# DataGridView taking more than usual to show records

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, datagridview

I have a class product

```
    class Product
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
enter code here
```

and a functions to insert and retrieve data from sql database using Dapper.

```
     public List<Product> GetProduct()
     {
        Connection conn = new Connection();
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conn.connect.ConnectionString))
            {
                return connection.Query<Product>($"Select Name,Image,ComboPrice from  Table_Products").ToList();
            }
     }

     public void InsertProduct(String name, byte[] image, Decimal price)
     {
            Connection conn = new Connection();
            using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(conn.connect.ConnectionString))
            {
                List<Product> product = new List<Product>();
                product.Add(new Product { Name = name, Image = image, ComboPrice = price });
                connection.Execute("Insert into Table_Products(Name,Image,ComboPrice) values(@Name,@Image,@ComboPrice)", product);
            }
     }
```

This is how i am inserting record in database after parsing image into byte.

```
    private void Insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] photo;
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(txtPhoto.Text))
        {
            photo = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(photo, 0, photo.Length);
        }
        db.InsertProduct(txt_description.Text,photo, Convert.ToDecimal(txt_price.Text));
    }
```

I have tried two ways to set datasource in a datagridview.

A simple one:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetProduct();
```

And using Async method:

```
    public async void LoadProduct()
    {
            await Task.Run(() => dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>{dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetProduct();})));
    }
```

**Issue**
*: Now The problem is sometimes even without Async method it pulls record and display all of them including images in less than a second. and very often it takes more than 10 seconds to display records with Async method and without Async too.*

**In short i don't know the issue is in my laptop or a code that i have written, also i want to know that have i written this code perfectly from performance perspective?**

Comment: The pseudo-async method doesn't make any sense. You ask for a ThreadPool Thread to just invoke back to the UI Thread right after. The pseudo-async method is probably slower -- The reason why it may take a long time to fetch the data is something you have to determine. Did you index your tables efficiently? How many records are you actually fetching? Do you have a remote connection and a busy / undersized network? All stuff that you can test. -- The DataGridView has a [VirtualMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode) that allows paging.

Comment: Currently table has only 126 rows.

Comment: Well, massive data transfer has been ruled out.